# Image within HTML List - without indenting text

Tags: javascript, html, css

Came across the below code to place a image at left of list item, but I need a different image in each list, also don't want the image to influence the text layout.

Is it possible to have a floating image in each list item, either behind or in front of the text.

I have tried several pieces of code and they seem to mess the text layout of the list, and destroy totally on a mobile device.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-image: url('sqpurple.gif');
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The list-style-image Property</h1>

<p>The list-style-image property replaces the list-item marker with an image:</p>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can style separately inline each li tag

Comment: Thanks for this but the image still pushes my text down, is there anyway I can make the image not effect the rest of the text?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use classes, like `.list-one`, etc.

```
ul.list-one {
  list-style-image: url('sqpurple.gif');
}
...
<ul class="list-one">
...
```

And then repeat for each of your lists with a `list-two` class, etc.

Working CodePen: https://codepen.io/mlillie87/pen/VwZaVwj

Comment: Thanks for this but the image still pushes my text down, is there anyway I can make the image not effect the rest of the text?